# Period after period (abbreviation at the end of a sentence)

Tags: punctuation, periods

If an abbreviation occurs at the end of sentence, is there one period or two? For example,

> Caesar was assassinated in 44 B.C.. Brutus killed him.

Should there be one period or two?

This has nothing to do with etc.

Comment: Periods are heavy-duty punctuation; one period can do two jobs at once.

Comment: @John: and even three: *My teacher said, "Caesar was assassinated in 44 B.C."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one. [Chicago manual of style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Punctuation/faq0040.html) covers this (with various examples).  Other style guides will usually agree (they don't on everything).  In your case *BC* is quite often used without punctuation anyway.